# R, separate columns separated by commas. more separations than into columns

Tags: r, dplyr

is it possible with dplyr and separate to create new lines if the separation produces more values than the specified "into" columns?

i.E.

```
df <- data.frame(values = c("1,2,3,4,5,6"))
sep <- separate(
    data = df,
    col = values,
    into = c("Part1", "Part2", "Part3"),
    sep = ","
)

sep
Part1 Part2 Part3
1     2     3
```

the expacted result looks like

```
sep
Part1 Part2 Part3
1     2     3
4     5     6
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Replace comma with semicolon after every third number, separate into rows and then separate into fields.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(values = gsub("(\\d+,\\d+,\\d+),", "\\1;", values)) %>%
  separate_rows(values, sep = ";") %>%
  separate(values, into = paste0("Part", 1:3), convert = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Part1 Part2 Part3
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     2     3
2     4     5     6
```

**2)** Alternately, replace the comma after every third field with newline and then use read.table to read it in.

```
library(dplyr)

df$values %>%
  gsub("(\\d+,\\d+,\\d+),", "\\1\n", .) %>%
  read.table(text = ., sep = ",", col.names = paste0("Part", 1:3))
```

giving:

```
  Part1 Part2 Part3
1     1     2     3
2     4     5     6
```

**3)** A variation of (2) is to scan it in, convert to matrix and then data frame and add column names.

```
df$values %>%
  scan(text = ., sep = ",", quiet = TRUE) %>%
  matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  setNames(paste0("Part", 1:ncol(.)))
```

giving:

```
  Part1 Part2 Part3
1     1     2     3
2     4     5     6
```